# Why is my line graph falling to 0 after each month and why is there a sudden spike in december? (this is in Tableau)

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence, linechart

[Revenue month chart of 2011](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x078m.png)

I am supposed to make line chart to analyse the revenue for each month in a particular year. So what should be done other than this? Is this one right?

Answer (score 0):

The Revenue column is the problem. I believe you want a continuous measure (Sum, Max, Avg etc) while you are now using a continuous dimension.

Remove the  Revenue from rows and bring a Sum(Revenue) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong chart type, and (perhaps) data aggregation issue - you want a bar chart by month, not a line-chart by day.